# Get Hosted service name by RoleEnvironment class in Azure

Tags: azure

In Azure webrole application is there any way to find hosted service details (Name) by **RoleEnvironment** class

I have done GET Request using by following request URI

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/deploymentslots/<deployment-slot>
```

If I am able to get hosted service name by this class then I can make this request possible with only certificate & subscription id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy answer here. RoleEnvironment class can provide information about the configuration, endpoints, and status of running role instances, but not the service name.

There is a work around though. You can get a list of all hosted services from Service Management API along with their deployment Ids for a subscription. You can then match it to RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId and you should have your answer.

Comment: thanks, I did exactly same way however in that case i need hosted service name , subscription-id & certificate

Comment: Does anything changed here since 2011?